# PHPUnit test for error thrown with wrong argument type

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm just starting with PHPUnit and am ok with all assert* methods, but can't figure out how to test for error thrown when the wrong argument is provided to the method - say hinted with `array` like so:

```
public function(array $list) { }
```

and then tested with `null` as argument.

Could someone please provide an example of how to test for this sort of errors?

I've checked quite a few posts on stackoverflow, but couldn't find the answer to this specific issue.

**Edit**

Ok - just to give you an idea of what I'm testing - here's the ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty() method:

```
public static function removeIfValueIsEmpty(array $array) {

    if (empty($array)) {

        return array();

    }

    return array_filter($array, function($value) {

        return !Helper::isEmpty($value);

    });

}
```

and now test:

```
class ArrayHelperTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testRemoveIfValueIsEmpty() {

        $this->assertEmpty(
            \Cmd\Helper\ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty(null),
            '\Cmd\Helper\ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty method failed (checking with null as argument)'
        );

    }

}
```

This throws an error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Error : Argument 1 passed to Cmd\Helper\ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty() must be of the type array, null given
```

Comment: we couldn't provide the help without complete description of your post with an example. you have to specify more

Comment: Well - there is an example - you have a public method with array type of the argument - and you want to test for null, but I don't know how to perform this test - hence the question. What else do you want me to put here?

Comment: Have you looked at PHPUnit's annotations? In particular [@expectedexception](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException). Having said that; why are you testing this? It is built in behaviour for PHP. You should be testing your code, not the language.

Comment: pass an empty array to your function?

Comment: nope - pass 'null' as argument in test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors

```
/**
* @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error
* @expectedExceptionMessage  Argument 1 passed to Cmd\Helper\ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty() must be of the type array, null given
*/
public function testRemoveIfValueIsEmpty() {

    \Cmd\Helper\ArrayHelper::removeIfValueIsEmpty(null);

}
```

Comment: Done, but I would call this testcase  testIfMethodHasArrayTypeHint.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, probably better name for the test.